# Low resolution test when convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have use this code to convert PDF file to JPEG images

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(90,90);
$im->readImage($pdf_file);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImages($save_to,false);
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

and it work but I have a problem that when there is a text with white background it will not be clear but I don't have this problem  when ever I have colored BG.

this image will make every thing clear
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG compression generates such artefacts on edges where there is big color differences (such as between your black text and your white background). Try to to [push up the compression quality](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php)
 or use another image format for images containing text (such as png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this functions:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(90,90);

if ($width < 300) $im->sharpenImage(4, 1);
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(100); // or some alse 

$im->readImage($pdf_file);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImages($save_to,false);
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: I get error `[20-Oct-2012 14:29:42] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object'`

Comment: Do you have memory available?

Comment: i don't know about the memory I use this in shared hosting. and for perl I don't know I will check it but i don't think it is the problem

Comment: I move readImage after the Resolution is set but now i get server error 500